# Replace ",**" with a linebreak using RegEx (or something else)

Tags: python, regex, string, kml

I'm getting started with RegEx and I was wondering if anyone could help me craft a statement to convert coordinates as follows:

```
145.00694,-37.80421,9 145.00686,-37.80382,9 145.00595,-37.8035,16 145.00586,-37.80301,16
```

to

```
145.00694,-37.80421
145.00686,-37.80382
145.00595,-37.8035 
145.00586,-37.80301
```

(Strip off the last comma and value and turn it into a line break.)

I can't figure out how to use wildcards to do something like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I used this http://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx in the past for writing regex, which is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think 'I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.' Now they have
>   two problems." --[Jamie Zawinski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Avoid that problem and use string methods:

```
s="145.00694,-37.80421,9 145.00686,-37.80382,9 145.00595,-37.8035,16 145.00586,37.80301,16"

lines = s.split(' ') # each line is separated by ' '
for line in lines:
    a,b,c=line.split(',') # three parts, separated by ','
    print a,b
```

Regex have their uses, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="145.00694,-37.80421,9 145.00686,-37.80382,9 145.00595,-37.8035,16 145.00586,-37.80301,16"
>>> print re.sub(",\d*\w","\n",s)
145.00694,-37.80421
145.00686,-37.80382
145.00595,-37.8035
145.00586,-37.80301
```

Comment: And this makes another great example of how fragile regex are: This only works as long as the 2nd number (-37.X) is negative ...

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that...how would I modify it to make it match ",[two digit number][white space]"? I'm trying ",\d\d\w" but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

String methods seem to suffice here, regex are overkill:

```
>>> s='145.00694,-37.80421,9 145.00686,-37.80382,9 145.00595,-37.8035,16 145.00586,-37.80301,16'
>>> print('\n'.join(line.rpartition(',')[0] for line in s.split()))
145.00694,-37.80421
145.00686,-37.80382
145.00595,-37.8035
145.00586,-37.80301
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '145.00694,37.80421,9 145.00686,-37.80382,9 145.00595,-37.8035,16 145.00586,-37.80301,16
>>> patt = '(%s,%s),%s' % (('[+-]?\d+\.?\d*', )*3)
>>> m = re.findall(patt, s)   
>>> m
['145.00694,37.80421', '145.00686,-37.80382', '145.00595,-37.8035', '145.00586,-37.80301']
>>> print '\n'.join(m)
145.00694,37.80421
145.00686,-37.80382
145.00595,-37.8035
145.00586,-37.80301
```

but I prefer **not** use regular expressions in this case

I like [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956044/replace-with-a-linebreak-using-regex-or-something-else/2956278#2956278) solution